# Combining draggable, droppable, sortable, tabs, clone accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have been trying to combine all the Interactions and Widgets mentioned above and som effects and i was able to do some of them successfully, as you can see in my "[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLopez/GsYpS/)".

But some of them like cloning the element when it's dragged to another tab, or making the accordion only work when it's pressed a  (minus icon in the panel title), or deffining only one tab to be droppable but not draggable.

Using [Connect lists with Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists-through-tabs) i was able to define a base to work.

I can remove the item (Sep1) with this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".glyphicon-remove").bind('click', $.proxy(function (event) {
        var status = $(event.target).attr('id').split("_");
        $("#chart_" + status[1] + "_" + status[2]).hide("drop", {
            direction: "up"
        }, "slow");
    }, this));
});
```

and partially do the accordion

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".glyphicon-minus").bind('click', $.proxy(function (event) {
        var status = $(event.target).attr('id').split("_");
        $("#accordion_" + status[1] + "_" + status[2]).accordion({
            collapsible: true
        });
    }, this));
});
```

the accordion problem is that after a click the button the first time it will apply the widget to all panel header and i only want it to apply it to a button.

Can anyone explain me how can i do it and if possible provide me some code with examples?

Comment: It looks like it is working, you can drag elements to the user tab and they appear there.

Comment: but if you drag an item to sep1 from sep2 it will disappear and will not appear in the other tab. I want to block that, if it's not the user tab the destination it cannot drop / disappear nad it will stay in it's beguining location (tab). I also want to leave a clone of the item in the tab when droppable is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a solution.
Here it is

```
$(function () {
$(".connectedSortable").sortable(
{
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    cursor: 'move',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    connectWith: 'ul.connectedSortable',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
}
).disableSelection();

var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();

var $tab_items = $("ul:first li", $tabs).droppable({
    accept: ".connectedSortable li",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: function (event, ui) {

        var source = $(ui.draggable[0]).parent().attr("id").split("-")[1];
        var target = $(event.target).children("a").attr("href").split("-")[1];

        if (source == target) {
            return false;
        }

        var $item = $(this);
        var $list = $($item.find("a").attr("href")).children();

        var $dragged = ui.draggable.clone().removeAttr('style');

        //var id = Check($dragged);

        //if (id != false) {

        var $chartId = "chart_0_" + id;
        var $accordionId = "accordion_0_" + id;
        var $minimizeId = "minimize_0_" + id;
        var $closeId = "close_0_" + id;

        $dragged.find("div[id^='chart']").attr("id", $chartId);
        $dragged.find("div[id^='accordion']").attr("id", $accordionId);
        $dragged.find("i[id^='minimize']").attr("id", $minimizeId);
        $dragged.find("i[id^='close']").attr("id", $closeId);

        if ((source == 1 || source == 2) && target === 0) {
            $tabs.tabs("option", "active", $tab_items.index($item));
            $dragged.appendTo($list);
        }
        //}
    }
});

$(".glyphicon-minus").click(function (event) { //ocultar grafico (panel body)
    var status = $(event.target).attr('id').split("_");
    $("#accordion_" + status[1] + "_" + status[2]).slideToggle("slow");
});

$(".glyphicon-remove").click(function (event) { // eliminar separador
    var status = $(event.target).attr('id').split("_");
    $("#chart_" + status[1] + "_" + status[2]).hide("drop", {
        direction: "up"
    }, "slow");
});

$(".glyphicon-floppy-save").click(function (event) { // guardar ordem de elementos dos separadores
    var $saveSortIds = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
        $saveSortIds[i] = $("#sortable-" + i).sortable("toArray"); //1 para cada separador         
});
```

});